# Little League Coach - What do I call myself?

Tags: pre-schooler, sports

What is the convention, should I call myself coach "first name" or coach "last name".  It's a team of 4 & 5 year olds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a common convention, but you may want to ask around the local area to see if there is a *local* convention.

Where I live (Midwestern US), the most frequent thing I've seen is "Coach first name", but it's mostly what you're comfortable with.  I usually introduce myself as "Coach Joe", but some of my kids will call me by my last name, and I don't discourage that.

Answer (score 0):

"Coach" and first name will feel like "Uncle Peter" ie a structure they will be familiar with, so go with that.